# Confusion about constructors

Tags: java, constructor

> Consider the following segment of code.
>
> ```
> SomeClass someObject1 = new SomeClass("Computer Science");
> SomeClass someObject2 = new SomeClass("Computer Science", "Rocks");
> SomeClass someObject3 = new SomeClass("Computer", "Science", "Rocks");
> ```
>
> Write complete constructors for each of these statements including the
>   assignment of variables.

I'm not sure exactly what this problem is looking for. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: A class can have multiple constructors. That's what's required there: you need to write them down.

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward.  They want you to define three constructors that take three different parameter signatures. You need data members defined in the class to store the state of the values that are passed in.   What do you need help understanding?

Answer (score 1):

so your answer will be

```
public SomeClass{

 String str1;
 String str2;
 String str3;

public SomeClass(String str1){
  this.str1=str1; 
}; 
public SomeClass(String str1,String str2){
this.str1=str1;
this.str2=str2;
}; 
public SomeClass(String str1,String str2,String str3){
this.str1=str1;
this.str2=str2;
this.str3=str3;
}; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar questions in my previous Java course. You are writing constructor for SomeClass. You are supposed to overload the constructor, e.g. it can accept a different number of arguments (different signatures).
Your second statement is missing quotes (").